# VS 2015 VB debug crashes when viewing an object

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution written in VB (with one C# project), which I am trying to debug in Visual Studio 2015. When I hit a breakpoint and hover over an object, the code crashes with the following error:

```
The program '[18348] MRS.ProductSupport.UI.vshost.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

I have not been able to find anything relevant on this error, or an explanation of why this is happening. There are some sites that say it is an IIS issue. My code does use a Web Service, but that is not being called from the section of code where I am debugging.

Oddly, I can view Properties of the object without crashing. For example, I have the following object:

```
item.FeatureID
```

I can hover over `FeatureID` and get a value. If I hover over `item`, the code crashes. I've resorted to using Debug.WriteLine to try to debug, but this is ideal. I am using Debug to view item Properties, but I have no way to examine the entire object.

This was previously an intermittent issue, but my system was updated to Windows 10, and now it seems that any object is causing the code to crash when I view it.

Just to clarify, if there are no breakpoints, the code runs. I am not dealing with null objects. I did try going into Properties -> Debug, and checking "Enable native code debugging" with no success. I am targeting .NET 4.

---

UPDATE:

During one of my testing sessions, Visual Studio crashed. When I reopened it, I was able to access the object and view all properties. I used the exact breakpoint, and examined the exact object as before. However, the next time I ran, the code crashed again. I exited Visual Studio and restarted, but this time the problem was not fixed.

I did attach a debugging process from a separate instance of VS, and was able to capture these errors:

```
Exception thrown at 0x768DDDC2 (KernelBase.dll) in devenv.exe: 0x80010108: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients (parameters: 0x2FD31E30).
    The thread 0x56ac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread 0x547c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread 0x55f4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    OnException: filter exception.
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DkmException: Error in the application.
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.VIL.VisualStudioHost.VilEvaluationServices.EvaluateToString(DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext, VilEvaluationResult evalResult)
       at VSDebugEngine.ClrInspector.EntryPoint.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.ComponentInterfaces.IDkmClrValueInspectionCallback.EvaluateToString(DkmClrValue clrValue, DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.EntryPoint.IDkmClrValueInspectionCallback_EvaluateToString(IntPtr pvClassInfo, IntPtr ClrValue, IntPtr InspectionContext, IntPtr& Result)'devenv.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscordacwks.dll'
    The thread 0x55e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    OnException: filter exception.
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DkmException: Error in the application.
       at XapiExceptionProcessing.ThrowHR(Int32 code)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Evaluation.ClrCompilation.DkmClrValue.EvaluateToString(DkmInspectionContext InspectionContext)
       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator.Formatter.GetValueString(DkmClrValue value, DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext, ObjectDisplayOptions options, GetValueFlags flags)
       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator.Formatter.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.ComponentInterfaces.IDkmClrFormatter.GetValueString(DkmClrValue value, DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext, ReadOnlyCollection`1 formatSpecifiers)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.EntryPoint.IDkmClrFormatter_GetValueString(IntPtr pvClassInfo, IntPtr ClrValue, IntPtr InspectionContext, IntPtr FormatSpecifiers, IntPtr& ValueString)The thread 0x2ccc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    OnException: filter exception.
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DkmException: Error in the application.
       at XapiExceptionProcessing.ThrowHR(Int32 code)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Evaluation.ClrCompilation.DkmClrValue.GetValueString(DkmInspectionContext InspectionContext, ReadOnlyCollection`1 FormatSpecifiers)
       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator.ResultProvider.GetResult(DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext, EvalResultDataItem dataItem, DkmClrType declaredType, DkmClrCustomTypeInfo declaredTypeInfo, String displayName, String displayValue, String displayType, EvalResultDataItem parent)
       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator.ResultProvider.GetResultAndContinue(EvalResultDataItem dataItem, WorkList workList, DkmClrType declaredType, DkmClrCustomTypeInfo declaredTypeInfo, DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext, EvalResultDataItem parent, CompletionRoutine`1 completionRoutine)
       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator.ResultProvider.GetRootResultAndContinue(DkmClrValue value, WorkList workList, DkmClrType declaredType, DkmClrCustomTypeInfo declaredTypeInfo, DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext, String name, CompletionRoutine`1 completionRoutine)
       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator.ResultProvider.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.ComponentInterfaces.IDkmClrResultProvider.GetResult(DkmClrValue value, DkmWorkList workList, DkmClrType declaredType, DkmClrCustomTypeInfo declaredTypeInfo, DkmInspectionContext inspectionContext, ReadOnlyCollection`1 formatSpecifiers, String resultName, String resultFullName, DkmCompletionRoutine`1 completionRoutine)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.EntryPoint.IDkmClrResultProvider_GetResult(IntPtr pvClassInfo, IntPtr ClrValue, IntPtr WorkList, IntPtr DeclaredType, IntPtr CustomTypeInfo, IntPtr InspectionContext, IntPtr FormatSpecifiers, IntPtr ResultName, IntPtr ResultFullName, IntPtr CompletionRoutine)Exception thrown at 0x768DDDC2 (KernelBase.dll) in devenv.exe: 0x80010108: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients (parameters: 0x2FD31D30).
    Exception thrown at 0x768DDDC2 (KernelBase.dll) in devenv.exe: 0x80010108: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients (parameters: 0x2FD31EB0).
```

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

I ran a GetType on the object I was looking at (named "item"), and then expanded it, and there were three visible exceptions. I honestly don't know if this is the cause of the problem, but figured I would share in case it helped:

- DeclaringMethod
- GenericParameterAttributes
- GenericParameterPosition

All three of these ran

```
DirectCast((item.GetType()), System.RuntimeType).DeclaringMethod
```

and all three received a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: What is item, is this object in a collection or list?

Comment: @Codexer - The objects are data objects. (This is not limited to one particular object though). The one in question is a list of custom objects that which ultimately inherits from List. It is a list of custom data objects, made of properties and a constructor also using inheritance. Note that my computer was recently updated (new C drive), and before that, I didn't have this issue.